# Writing dataframe in a csv file is removing leading spaces from string column

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Suppose I have a csv file:

```
UserName
"Ali "
"Bilal "
"Ahsan "
```

When I read this in Spark, data is correct.

```
------------
- UserName -
------------
- Ali      -
- Bilal    -
- Ahsan    -
```

But when I write this back in a csv file then spaces are removed and the file has output

```
UserName
"Ali"
"Bilal"
"Ahsan"
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While writing, use option ignoreLeadingWhiteSpace and ignoreTrailingWhiteSpace is true. by default they are true while writing csv in spark and false when reading. See: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-csv.html

```
df.write.format("csv").option("ignoreTrailingWhiteSpace",true)..option("ignoreLeadingWhiteSpace",true).save(path)
```

please accept answer if it solves.

Comment: Thanks, yeah thats the right answer. It will ignore the whitespaces while writing.

Comment: @deo/@Bilal Shafqat - Does it work for Spark 2.2.0. I did add the options to ignore white spaces but it did not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

There is a function for that built into sql functions.

```
scala> import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.trim
scala> import spark.implicits

scala> val names = Seq(" Ali ", "Bihal ", " Ahsan").toDF("n")
names: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [n: string]

scala> names.withColumn("n", trim($"n")).show(1)
+---+
|  n|
+---+
|Ali|
+---+
only showing top 1 row


scala> names.withColumn("n", trim($"n")).show
+-----+
|    n|
+-----+
|  Ali|
|Bihal|
|Ahsan|
+-----+
```

Comment: thanks for replying, but this will remove the whitespaces but I dont want to remove whitespaces, I want them as they are.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I totally misread that question... Perhaps you could have explicitly stated "can you guys please help telling me how to NOT remove the white spaces."  As you can see from the response that is what we all read from what was written.

Comment: Escaping quotes within your dataframe seems to do what you want it to. val names = Seq(("\" Ali \"", "\"A+\""), ("\"Bihal \"", "\"A-\""), ("\" Ahsan\"", "\"B+ \"")).toDF("n", "g") \n names.repartition(1).write.mode("overwrite").option("quote", "\"").option("escape", "\"").csv("./trash"). Or, store it in a better and faster format like parquet. CSV is usually only an input step now days, but after ingested, most everything stays in parquet format.